# uploading image in mysql and to a specific directory using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code for upload.php, i want to upload the image in a directory and save its path to mysql database.

The image is successfully uploaded to the directory, but its entry doesn't get inserted into the database.

- upload.php

```php
<?php

require("connect.php");

if (isset($_FILES["userfile"]) && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {                                        
$image = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];                                   
$imageName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];                                   
$about = $_POST['about'];                                   
$title = $_POST['title'];                                       
$place = $_POST['place'];                                       
$date = $_POST['date'];                                     
$time = $_POST['time'];                                     
$link = $_POST['link'];                                 
$details = $_POST['details'];                                       
$con = $_POST['con'];                                   
$email = $_POST['email'];                                       
$number = $_POST['number'];                                 
$len = count($image);                                   
$path = "admin/news/";                                  
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {                                      
    if (isset($imageName[$i]) && $imageName[$i] !== NULL) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($image[$i], $path.$imageName[$i])) {
             mysqli_query($con,"insert into tblnews (newsid, about,    date_of_event, time, link, event_place, title, details, image, date, contactperson, email, number) values('','$about','$date','$time','$link','$place','$title','$details','$imageName[1]',NOW(),'$con','$email','$number')");
                   echo"<script>alert('The news had been successfuly uploaded.')
                   window.location='index.php?pg=homepage'</script>";
                                 }
                             }
               }
}
?>
```

- HTML form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>About</th>
            <td>
                <select name="about">
                    <option disabled  selected>Select</option>
                    <option value="Taal">Taal Volcano</option>
                    <option value="Malarayat">Mt. Malarayat Forest Reserve</option>
                    <option value="vip">Verde Island Passage</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="title" required ></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Event's Place</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="place" required  ></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Event Date</th>
            <td><input type="date" name="date" required></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Event Time</th>
            <td><input type="time" name="time"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <td><input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple='multiple' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Link on Facebook</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="link"></input></td>
            <td><span>Go to the facebook page of the event and copy the url and paste it in the textbox.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Details</th>
            <td><textarea name="details" style="height:250px;" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Contact Person</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="con" required  ></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>Email</th>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" required  ></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="number" ></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input type="submit" name="add_news" value="Upload"></input></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you sending `newsid` to `NULL`?
is `newsid` primary key and autoincrement?

Comment: Multiple criticism concerning your question: could you post only a minimal code example of what you want to accomplish. Then try using [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), this would help with your problem and the security issue you will have with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of inserting `variable` directly into your query.

And as @ajaykumartak pointed out newsid is likely an **auto-increment key** and **do not need to be set** in insertion.

Modification to your code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($image[$i], $path.$imageName[$i])) {
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    $query = <<<END 
        insert into tblnews (
            about,
            date_of_event, 
            time, 
            link,
            event_place, 
            title, 
            details, 
            image, 
            date, 
            contactperson, 
            email, 
            number
        )
        values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
END;
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ssssssssssss',
         $about, $date, $time, $link,
         $place, $tile, $details, $imageName[$i],
         $date, $contactperson, $email, $number
    );
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Of course you should also check for the return values of the function call to verify that they execute correctly, because I only inferred your table structure. You would need to check the error with `mysqli_error` :

```
echo ( mysqli_error($con) );
```